# Insert into a table if a condition is met with sqlite3

Tags: insert, sqlite, conditional-statements

if I have two tables: `files(id, owner)` and `share(file_id, user)`, where owner and user would be primary IDs from a theoretical user table, how can I insert an entry into `share` only if the user doing the sharing owns that file?

This is a stripped down example, so I'll just use a literal for the one doing the share operation -- normally this value would come from a session. So if I had:

```
files:
id: 1, owner: 1
```

and user 2 wants to see file 1, I would use this query:

```
insert into share values (1, 2)
```

but that isn't allowed -- user 2 doesn't own file 1, user 1 does. I am trying to do this in one query, but I can't figure it out. I have tried:

```
case when (select owner from files where id=1) is 2
    then (insert into share values (1, 2));

case (select owner from files where id=1) is 2
    then (insert into share values (1, 2));

insert into share values (1, 2)
    where 2 not in (select owner from files where id=1)
```

and they are all syntax errors. I'm doing this from Python, so after this query, I would just check the `Cursor.rowcount` to see if it is 1 or 0, and if it's 0, then the user didn't have permission to complete the operation.

How can I properly write this query?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Allow me to suggest my approach as an answer:

```
insert into share select id,2 as file_id from files where id=1 and owner=2;
```

No need for a `not null` clause or foreign key in your Share table, no exception to catch.

Comment: this is awesome -- I actually recently found out I could just use a literal as a selected field, and actually tried this. It can be simplified to `insert into share select id, 2 ...` no need for values. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. And yes, no need for values. I wonder why I put that in... Allow me to edit the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I found one way I could do it, though it's not the solution I was hoping to find. I could add `not null` and/or a foreign key to the `file_id` column in the `share` table, and then try running this query:

```
insert into share
    values(
        (select id as file_id from files where id=1 and owner=2),
        2
    );
```

that way the select query will return nothing if the user doesn't own the file id, and the not null and/or foreign key constraint will fail and I will get an exception in Python.

If anyone knows the real solution to this please let me know, I feel awfully dirty using this approach.

Comment: Don't feel dirty. CASE in SQLite is only used in a select query. I'd say that's a fine workaround.

Comment: I would prefer `select id,2` over `(select id),2` because in the former, on 0 rows returned, it is clear your insert will not attempt anything and thus not return an exception.

Comment: `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO share`